# Unable to install sasl-0.1.3 python package on windows machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, sasl

I am trying to install sasl-0.1.3 python package on windows 7 (64 bit machine).
It is fialing wiht C1083 fatal error.

Looks like saslwrapper.cpp is unable to include sasl/sasl.h library in c++ module.

[image]

Please help me in resolving the issue. Let me know if you need more details.

I installed python 2.7 on my machine.

Comment: Identified the issue and found the solution here http://www.chriscalender.com/resolving-saslsasl-h-not-found-during-cmake-when-building-mysql-on-windows/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The easier way I find to install sasl on windows 7 is to use the pre-compiled version from here : [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

There is a direct link to the sasl librairies here : [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl) just pick the one you need.

Then you install it using pip :

```
pip install sasl-0.1.3-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: This really solved the issue of installing pyhs2 on Windows 7 , 64-bit, thanks @loicmathieu. It should be voted as the correct answer.

Comment: The download link is broken. You can find here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl

Comment: there is no file available for win64. Is there any alterantive?

Comment: Hi, the file in the answer is for win64 (it's called amd64 ... this just means the 64bit CPU architecture)

Comment: PS C:\tools> pip install .\sasl-0.1.3-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: sasl-0.1.3-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\eugene_wang\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: ERROR: sasl-0.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: PS C:\tools> pip install .\sasl-0.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\tools\sasl-0.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl ,! YOU HAVE TO install this wheel EXACTLY the same version as your Python Version, or else it gives error!

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a sasl version 0.2.1 for p310 - which is a requirement of some packages such as impala shell. This solution does work to get sasl installed but we need more wheels for older sasl versions

Answer (score 7):

### Automated install approach

In the interest of getting to high levels of automation, and to hopefully save other users time, the below works also for automated installations. (Substitute a different mirror URL if needed.)

```
pip install https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/g5apjq5m/sasl-0.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Also, be advised the "cp37" text in the file name is important - you'll want to match this text to the version of python you are using. I am on Python 3.7, which is cp37 (aka CPython 3.7). ([More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37028661/4298208).)

As of the time of this post, the available version/platform combinations are:

```
sasl‑0.1.3‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl
sasl‑0.1.3‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl
sasl‑0.2.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
sasl‑0.2.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
sasl‑0.2.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl
sasl‑0.2.1‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
sasl‑0.2.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
sasl‑0.2.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
sasl‑0.2.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
sasl‑0.2.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.
```

### Automated install of the VS C++ Tools and and sasl at the same time.

*The below is a fully-automated install of everything you need.*

1. From an elevated command prompt, install the Choco package manager (if you have not already).

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

2. Install C++ Build Tools

```
choco install microsoft-visual-cpp-build-tools
```

3. Install Sasl
   (*customize the URL per the above guidance*)

```
pip install https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/g5apjq5m/sasl-0.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Thanks to @loicmathieu for the original fix! This answer expands upon the original, with additional automation details and some info on the various version/platform options.

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents for those who use `pipenv` and want the package be installed on both Linux and Windows, the following worked for me (`sasl 0.2.1`):

```
[packages]
...
sasl = {version = "==0.2.1", markers = "platform_system == 'Linux'"}
sasl_win = {version = "==0.2.1", markers = "platform_system == 'Windows'", file = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/g5apjq5m/sasl-0.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"}
...
```

See the [comment on the corresponding Github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3581#issuecomment-469980643).