# What does version name 'cp27' or 'cp35' mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What does version name 'cp27' or 'cp35' mean in Python?

Like the files in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim#downloads

[image]

I am using Python 2.7 on a 64-bit Window 7 PC, and don't know which version of python package I should install.

There are three questions:

1. Which of "**gensim-0.12.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl**" or "**gensim-0.12.4.win-amd64-py2.7.exe**" should I install?  I have installed 'WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3' on 64-bit Window 7 PC which I am using.
2. What does '**cp27**' mean in Python or Python version name? I searched online with keywords 'Python cp27' but failed to find any answers.
3. Are there differences between these two versions of python packages? ('**0.12.4-cp27-none-win_amd64**' and '**win-amd64-py2.7**') If there are, what are the differences?

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing, but the broad meaning should not be hard to guess - CPython versions 2.7 and 3.5?

Comment: The precompiled executable is packaged differently than the wheel, but the contents are fundamentally the same. The former makes sense in a standalone installation, whereas the latter is useful for e.g. development.

Comment: Only one question per question, please.

Comment: @tripleee see my answer for links to the docs :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you check out the [Python Enhancement Proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/) (more commonly known as a PEP), you'll see that the `cpN` refers to the particular version of Python

in `gensim-0.12.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` you can break it apart:

- **0.12.4** - package version, they *may* be using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org)
- **cp27** - this package is for CPython. IronPython, Jython, or PyPy will probably be unhappy.
- **none** - no feature of this package depends on the python [Application Binary Interface, or ABI](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html)
- **win_amd64** - this has been compiled for 64-bit Windows. That means that it probably has some code written in C/C++
- **.whl** - that means this is a wheel distribution. Which is handy, because it means if you're running CPython 2.7 64-bit on Windows, and assuming you have pip installed, all you have to do to get this package is run: `py -2.7 -m pip install --use-wheel gensim` (assuming that it's available on pypi, of course). You *may* need to `py -2.7 -m pip install wheel` first. But other than that, that should be all it takes.

Comment: What is the `m` suffix? ie `cp37m`.

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute it looks like it's part of the ABI tag

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute --with-pymalloc (flag: m)

Answer (score 11):

These stand for the version of CPython (i.e. the Python official distribution you get from python.org) which the wheel files are built for.

For example `cp27` is meant to be used on a CPython version 2.7.

Warning: `cp32` is meant to be used in a CPython version 3.2. The difference between the 32 bits version and the 64 bits version is stated in another suffix, e.g. `win32` or `amd64` in the filename.

Comment: There's now a pp38 - what does this mean?

Comment: @yeliabsalohcin It's related to pypy, another implementation of python