# What is the meaning of 'cp3xm' and 'cp2xm' in the name of Python wheels?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

To my knowledge, the naming rules of python wheel is

```
package_version-related_python_version-none-32bits_or_64bits.whl
```

For example,

```
numpy‑1.11.2+mkl‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

is numpy of version 1.11.2 for Python3.5 running in windows 64 bits platform.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023557/what-does-version-name-cp27-or-cp35-mean-in-python)

Currently i have noticed the naming of Python packages in [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) use 'cpxxm' to replace 'none'. For example,

```
numpy‑1.11.2+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
```

When installing these packages, pip will return version unmatch error. When i change 'cp35m' to 'none', it becomes normal.

So, what is the meaning of 'cp2xm' 'cp3xm' and why suddenly all the package replace 'none' with 'cpxxm'?

Comment: `m` means version with different memory manager. There is information somewhere in documentation. On Linux I have automatically installed files `python3` and `python3m` so I can choose which version run.

Comment: @furas How can i change Python3 to Python3m in windows?

Comment: look in folder with Python, maybe you have both files installed `python3` and `python3m` or something similar like `py3.exe`, `py3m.exe`. Then you have to use `py3m.exe script.py` to run script with this version. I don't use Windows so I can't help it.

Comment: It is said that PyMalloc is not yet implemented on windows. But there is some packages for py3m on windows. That really confuses me.

Answer (score 6):

From [PEP 3149](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/) the `m` indicates `pymalloc` is in use as the memory allocator

The second component of the wheel name is the "abi" component.  This was always `none` in wheels produced by older versions of wheel `<26` as abi detection wasn't yet implemented.

In newer versions of wheel, the abi is populated. You need a sufficiently new version of pip in order to install these wheels.