# ERROR: torch-1.10.0+cu113-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: pytorch

I tried to install pytorch from site using,

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cu113 torchvision==0.11.1+cu113 torchaudio===0.10.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```

That didn't work, so I downloaded it from
'https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html'
and now I have a file called `torch-1.10.0+cu113-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`
How do I install it using pip?

Answer (score 1):

pip3 install torch-1.10.0+cu113-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

You need to ensure you have CPython 3.6 otherwise you may get an error saying the file is not a supported wheel on this platform. Also, this package is compiled for 64bit Windows, so you need to be on that architecture.

More on the naming convention in this answer:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023557/what-does-version-name-cp27-or-cp35-mean-in-python#:~:text=win_amd64%20%2D%20this%20has%20been%20compiled,this%20is%20a%20wheel%20distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023557/what-does-version-name-cp27-or-cp35-mean-in-python#:%7E:text=win_amd64%20%2D%20this%20has%20been%20compiled,this%20is%20a%20wheel%20distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.10.0+cpu
```