# sasl installation in Windows

Tags: python, windows, sasl

I am using Python 3.4.2 on windows 64bit system. When I am trying to install sasl using pip, I am getting the error  `error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty`

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install sasl
Collecting sasl
  Using cached sasl-0.2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\python34\lib
\site-packages (from sasl)
Installing collected packages: sasl
  Running setup.py install for sasl ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-f0i1e62f
\\sasl\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().
replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\username\\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-_x6vls5i-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externall
y-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    copying sasl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    running egg_info
    writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to sasl.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing sasl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    running build_ext
    building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
    error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty
```

**EDIT**

After installing `Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4` and `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable` it resolved the above issue.

Now I am getting the error `Cannot open include file: 'sasl/sasl.h'`

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install sasl
Collecting sasl
  Using cached sasl-0.2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\python34\lib
\site-packages (from sasl)
Installing collected packages: sasl
  Running setup.py install for sasl ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-m7m3weo7
\\sasl\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().
replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\username\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-rz3nmdwp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externall
y-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    copying sasl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    running egg_info
    writing sasl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing requirements to sasl.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    copying sasl\saslwrapper.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\sasl
    running build_ext
    building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\sasl
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe
/c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isasl -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\
include /Tpsasl/saslwrapper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\sasl/saslwra
pper.obj
    saslwrapper.cpp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\xlocale(323)
: warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enable
d. Specify /EHsc
    c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-m7m3weo7\sasl\sasl\saslwrapper.
h(22) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sasl/sasl.h': No such file
 or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\B
in\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: Try loicmathieu's solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35985464/6885397 (just use one of the \*cp34\*.whl in your case (the one for your CPU's arch) instead of the quoted \*cp27\*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install sasl-0.1.3 python package on windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505882/unable-to-install-sasl-0-1-3-python-package-on-windows-machine)