# Running setup.py install for sasl ... error

Tags: pip, python-3.6, sasl

when I try to install sasl on my python3.6 in Windows10, I got an error.

I hava tried the best answer in: [Unable to install sasl-0.1.3 python package on windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505882/unable-to-install-sasl-0-1-3-python-package-on-windows-machine)

It still does not work.Maybe cause of the version of python or environment of operating system. Anyway please help me to install sasl in python3.x. It will be perfect in Windows also.

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: if I put 'pip install sasl', I got 'Running setup.py install for sasl … error
'

Comment: if I download resource and put 'pip install sasl-0.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl', I got 'sasl-0.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem finally, I am really stupid!!!
My Python Version is 32bit, hhhhhaaa....
After I changed to Version 64bit, it is worked.
Although sasl is not easy to install, what is a luck that there are so many article relate to it.