# How to install SASL with Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.8, sasl, pyhive

I am trying to install sasl3-0.2.11 python package on a windows 10 machine (64 bit).
It is failing with a C1083 fatal error.

Due to some proxies and me not being able to avoid them, I am installing it by downloading the tar.gz from pypi, logging into the uncompressed folder and doing `python setup.py install`.

This solution worked for all modules but sasl.

I have then read this [useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505882/unable-to-install-sasl-0-1-3-python-package-on-windows-machine) but the .whl from Cyrus Sasl did not work too. They suppot until 3.7 python, not 3.8.

I am really wondering how can I bypass this issue or could I avoid sasl for being able to use Pyhive.

Thanks in advance.

Nourou

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install the following packages on Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libsasl2-dev libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
```

Comment: This directly solved the issue for me. I didn't need to run any other commands besides the above and `pip install sasl`

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I just uninstalled Python 3.8 and install the 3.7.
Then, I was able to install Sasl via the wheel file [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl)