# Precompiled sasl python 3.9+ package for windows

Tags: python, windows, sasl

I'm looking for a pre-compiled sasl package for Windows python 3.9 or higher.

Since compiling the package seems quite some effort I'd prefer a pre-compiled package.  There are some questions about problems when installings sasl (e.g. [unable-to-install-sasl-0-1-3-python-package-on-windows-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505882/unable-to-install-sasl-0-1-3-python-package-on-windows-machine)).  But all of them refer to py3.7 or below.

There is no py3.9 version in the mentioned repos:
e.g. [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl)

Other mentioned repos are no longer available, e.g. https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/g5apjq5m/

Comment: Python-sasl compiles on POSIX platforms only (uses getpass).

Comment: Wer are currently using a pre-compiled package for 3.7 (see 1st link) on Windows.  So it can be compiled on/for Windows.  This effort is exactly what I'm trying to avoid if someone else has gone through it.

Comment: It's possible to work around the build failure. See https://github.com/cloudera/python-sasl/pull/29

Comment: Cool! So the repo mentioned above is yours?  Once this is merged can you upload an according version?  That would be perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo was updated again by @cgohlke.

So versions for 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10 can now be found here again:

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl)