# Can't install sasl on Windows 10 Python 3.10

Tags: python, impala, sasl

*This issue has been raised before but not resolved for Windows 10 users as far as i can tell.*

I am trying to install impala-shell for python but it is failing when trying to install sasl 0.2.1. It fails due to **"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sasl/sasl.h': No such file or directory"**

There are several other resolutions which suggest using *"apt-get install libsasl2-dev"* - but this is not possible on windows, which instead has a folder python/include for header files.

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: Note: impala-shell seems to insist on sasl 0.2.1. I managed to install v0.3.1 via a wheel file, but the installer attempts to uninstall this first and then install 0.2.1. I have not been able to find a wheel file for sasl 0.2.1 which works with windows 64 python 3.10

Comment: You could run your code in WSL2 or Docker Linux container instead as a workaround

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't know how to do that (or if that is the right thing to do). Surely engineers should be able to install packages like this in windows

Comment: It was more a comment related to your apt-get suggestion. [More about WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about). For Windows directly, there seems to be relevant solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/q/26505882/2308683 , but also you need to consider where your code will actually run when _deployed_, not just when testing locally on your Windows machine

Comment: Thank you for the advice. From what I've read it's a really good point about what happens when it's deployed (airflow). It sounds like I will actually need something like docker for that

Comment: Airflow doesn't always use a Docker executor, so you may want to ask the people running that